# Не отображается изображение Django

Tags: django

Есть модель `poster = models.URLField('Ссылка на постер')`
и шаблон

```html
    <img src="{{ movie.poster }}" alt="{{ movie.title }} постер">
```

И после добавления любой ссылки на изображения в админ панели она не отображается.
Но если я делаю модель с загрузкой файла `poster = models.ImageField('Постер', upload_to='movies/')`
и шаблон

```html
    <img src="{{ movie.poster.url }}" alt="">
```

то все отображается, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Два логичных вопроса: первый — какое в итоге значение-то получается в атрибуте src? И второй — что вы предприняли для того, чтобы по этому самому значению  отдавалось изображение?